# how to hide div onclick anywhere on page using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I have created a multiselect but need to hide that option palate on click anywhere on page how to do this action in jquery. am using this But it's not working.

Hello I have created a multiselect but need to hide that option palate on click anywhere on page how to do this action in jquery. am using this But it's not working.

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $('.multiselectBox-option').hide();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click','.multiselectBox', function(){
  $('.multiselectBox-option').toggle();
});


$(".multiselectItem").change(function(event){
    if (this.checked){
     var x = $(this).val();

    $('.multiselectBox').append(x+','+'&n');

    } else {
        alert("You have elected to turn off checkout history.");
    }
});
```

```css
 .multiselectBox{
            padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
            background-color: #F8F9FB;
            border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
            height: 36px;
            cursor: pointer;
    }
    
     .multiselectBox-option {
        background: #f8f9fb;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
        border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
    }
    
    .multiselectBox-option ul{
       list-style: none;
       padding-left: 0px;
    
    }
    
    .arrow-down {
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-top: 10px solid #022255;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
                             <div class="multiselectBox mt-3">
                                 <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="multiselectBox-option" style="display: none;">
                               <ul>
                                 <li><input type="checkbox" class="multiselectItem" value="Smoking Materials"/> <span>Smoking Materials</span></li>
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" class="multiselectItem" value="Heating Equipment"/> <span>Heating Equipment</span></li>
                                  
                               </ul>
                             </div>
                             </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function, when user click outside the multiselect close it. like:

```js
$(document).on('click','.multiselectBox', function(){
  $('.multiselectBox-option').toggle();
});

$(".multiselectItem").change(function(event){
    if (this.checked){
     var x = $(this).val();

    $('.multiselectBox').append(x+','+'&n');

    } else {
        alert("You have elected to turn off checkout history.");
    }
});
//Close only if not click to multiselectbox
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest(".multiselectBox").length && !$(event.target).closest(".multiselectBox-option").length ) {
        $(".multiselectBox-option").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.multiselectBox{
            padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
            background-color: #F8F9FB;
            border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
            height: 36px;
            cursor: pointer;
    }
    
     .multiselectBox-option {
        background: #f8f9fb;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
        border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
    }
    
    .multiselectBox-option ul{
       list-style: none;
       padding-left: 0px;
    
    }
    
    .arrow-down {
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-top: 10px solid #022255;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
                             <div class="multiselectBox mt-3">
                                 <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="multiselectBox-option" style="display: none;">
                               <ul>
                                 <li><input type="checkbox" class="multiselectItem" value="Smoking Materials"/> <span>Smoking Materials</span></li>
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" class="multiselectItem" value="Heating Equipment"/> <span>Heating Equipment</span></li>
                                  
                               </ul>
                             </div>
                             </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for efforts, But option palate should not hide once we checked option. Because of this user would have to show palate again and again for check every option , it should hide when click on another area of screen.

Comment: Done, i simple add `.multiselectBox-option` to the `if`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can place a class on the `div` which wraps both the select box and its option list.

Then you can attach an event handler to the `document` which hides all the option lists, so long as the target element which was clicked was not the select or the option list.

Try this:

```js
let $doc = $(document);

$doc.on('click', '.multiselectBox', function() {
  $('.multiselectBox-option').toggle();
});

$doc.on('click', e => {
  let $target = $(e.target);
  if (!$target.is('.multiselectBox-container') && !$target.closest('.multiselectBox-container').length) {
    $('.multiselectBox-option').hide();
  }    
}); 

$(".multiselectItem").change(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.multiselectBox').append(x + ',' + '&n');
  } else {
    alert("You have elected to turn off checkout history.");
  }
});
```

```css
.multiselectBox {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #F8F9FB;
  border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.multiselectBox-option {
  background: #f8f9fb;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #707070 !important;
}

.multiselectBox-option ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #022255;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselectBox-container">
  <div class="multiselectBox mt-3">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="multiselectBox-option" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="multiselectItem" value="Smoking Materials" /> <span>Smoking Materials</span></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="multiselectItem" value="Heating Equipment" /> <span>Heating Equipment</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't our answers the same?

Comment: Not quite, as prior to your edit the code in your answer closed the box on every click, not just those outside the options list

Comment: Now is all ok :)